# How to get jQuery.mmenu to slide over the content instead of "pushing" it

Tags: javascript, jquery, mmenu

I'm using [jQuery.mmenu](http://mmenu.frebsite.nl/) in a project. The plugin by default slides out a menu (navigation bar) at the left side of the screen which pushes the entire side towards the right. I'm no Javascript/jQuery crack...

Does anyone know how I could alter the [code](http://mmenu.frebsite.nl/mmenu/js/jquery.mmenu.min.all.js) of the plugin to get the menu slide **over my content** rather than pushing it to the right.

Thanks in advance...

EDIT: I usually use SIdr for my sliding menus. To achieve the above with Sidr all it takes is changing 'true' to 'false' on a certain command. I was hoping it'd be something simple like that in this case, too.

On my current project however I'm having to deal with a very complex navigation with tons of sub-menus, Sidr won't do the job here. PLUS mmenu seems pretty neat - if I could only figure how it slides the way i want.

Comment: Not sure why I am getting so heavily downvoted? Is that question too vague? Am I asking too much? 

I edited the question a little...maybe it stops people from downvoting it... ;-)

Comment: I was not a downvoter, but yes what you're asking a very broad question - a complete solution to be done for you. Also, you linked to the minified / obfuscated code, which isn't terribly helpful. What would be better is for you to figure out how that library does its job, and determine how to modify that behaviour. Also double check the documentation to see whether this feature already exists as a configurable option, or something like that. Perhaps it already does that?

Comment: And feel free to post back here when you're encountered a specific problem or question (that has not already been answered).

Comment: Thanks Paul! 

I didn't mean to have the job done for me. ;-) I've been through nearly all stackoverflow question on the mmslider I could find.

Couldn't find anything on that particular issue.

If there would've been any source code other than the .min I would've posted that. I just thought a minified code is better than none at all.

My understanding of jQuery/JavaScript isn't going far enough to figure out how the library does what it does, no matter how long I'm going to read through...hence the post.

Comment: Anyway, thanks again for clarifying, but I assure you this post wasn't the first thing I did...there were lots of searches (Google & here) before.

Comment: Yeah, idk why there were so many downvotes...I need the same thing myself (after spending a while reading documentation searching for the answer to this. It was not easy to find.)

Comment: I had the same doubt. You made it easy. Thank you @TheGmo!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After taking a quick look at the documentation and the demos, [this one](http://mmenu.frebsite.nl/demo/menu-custom.html) appears to be the most relevant to what you're looking for. As you will see, in this example the menu is pulled down overtop of the page content, rather than pushing it aside.

Based on your description, you want something that pulls out left to right, rather than top to bottom as this example does, and the option that appears to control that is the [`off-canvas` option](http://mmenu.frebsite.nl/documentation/addons/off-canvas.html). Changing the `position`  from `top` to `left` changes the position of the menu:

```
$("#menu").mmenu({
    offCanvas : {
        position : "left", // changing this alters the position of the menu
        zposition : "front"
    }
})
```

[This JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kwzgrq09/19/) from @Gaurang Patel demonstrates this behaviour.

Comment: *Despite my earlier statement...* As an aside, despite you being very new to javascript and such, always read through the documentation and examples. In this case, I solved it by simply finding something that very closely matched your goal, and then found what controlled the behaviour, and changed the options until it adequately matched the desired behaviour. A general rule of thumb, even for seasoned developers, is if you find yourself considering a solution which goes **way** out of your way and requires a ton of work, its likely to be the least optimal solution.

Comment: Thanks Paul. Although development on this site is done, I very much appreciate that you took the time to help solve the issue.

Comment: Sounds good @TheGmo, I appreciate the answer-accept. Good luck in your work!

Comment: Fix suggested by @PaulRicher is perfect. I have tested it on jQuery mmenu v5.3.2. However, mentioned JsFiddle link had stopped working due to missing external links.. [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/kwzgrq09/19/) is the working fiddle..

Comment: @GaurangPatel Thanks for the updated link. I'll add it to the answer with proper credit.